# Sum multiple variables by group and create new column with their sum

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with grouped variable and I want to sum them by group. It's easy with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), n1 = 1:5, n2 = 2:6)

data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   group    n1    n2
  <fctr> <int> <int>
1      a     3     5
2      b     3     4
3      c     9    11
```

But now I want a new column `total` with the sum of `n1` and `n2` by group. Like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   group    n1    n2   ttl
  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
1      a     3     5     8
2      b     3     4     7
3      c     9    11    20
```

How can I do that with `dplyr`?

**EDIT:**
Actually, it's just an example, I have a lot of variables.

I tried these two codes but it's not in the right dimension...

```
data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)

data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = sum)
```

Comment: I edited to avoid confusion: I have a lot of variables and I don't want to do n1+n2+...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mutate` after `summarize`:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>% 
    mutate(tt1 = n1 + n2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   group    n1    n2   tt1
#  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
#1      a     3     5     8
#2      b     3     4     7
#3      c     9    11    20
```

---

If need to sum all numeric columns, you can use `rowSums` with `select_if` (to select numeric columns) to sum columns up:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>% 
    mutate(tt1 = rowSums(select_if(., is.numeric)))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   group    n1    n2   tt1
#  <fctr> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1      a     3     5     8
#2      b     3     4     7
#3      c     9    11    20
```

Comment: I edited to avoid confusion: I have a lot of variables and I don't want to do n1+n2+...

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` together with the `dplyr` functions.

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), n1 = 1:5, n2 = 2:6)

data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  mutate(ttl = apply(.[, 2:ncol(.)], 1, sum))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
   group    n1    n2   ttl
  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
1      a     3     5     8
2      b     3     4     7
3      c     9    11    20
```

Or `rowSums` with the same strategy. The key is to use `.` to specify the data frame and `[]` with `x:ncol(.)` to keep the columns you want.

```
data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  mutate(ttl = rowSums(.[, 2:ncol(.)]))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
   group    n1    n2   ttl
  <fctr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1      a     3     5     8
2      b     3     4     7
3      c     9    11    20
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'group', get the `sum` of each columns in the Subset of data.table, and then with `Reduce`, get the `sum` of the rows of the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, sum) , group][, tt1 := Reduce(`+`, .SD),  
                       .SDcols = names(data)[-1]][]
#   group n1 n2 tt1
#1:     a  3  5   8
#2:     b  3  4   7
#3:     c  9 11  20
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
addmargins(as.matrix(rowsum(data[-1], data$group)), 2)
#  n1 n2 Sum
#a  3  5   8
#b  3  4   7
#c  9 11  20
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
data %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarise_all(sum) %>% 
   mutate(tt = rowSums(.[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
cbind(aggregate(.~group, data, sum), ttl = sapply(split(data[,-1], data$group), sum))
#  group n1 n2 ttl
#a     a  3  5   8
#b     b  3  4   7
#c     c  9 11  20
```